# SQL wrong result in calculating week

Tags: sql, date, mariadb-10.4

My query result is getting the week wrong. I have this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `p_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `p_date`, `amount`) VALUES
(4, '2024-01-02 13:15:38', 150);
```

I try to catch the post in the table with this query:

```
SELECT 
amount,
date_format(p_date, '%u') as week, 
date_format(p_date, '%Y') as year
FROM test
WHERE week(p_date) = 1
AND year(p_date) = 2024
```

this returns empty. However, if I change the week to 0 it fetches the post. But the date 2024-01-02 is in week 1. So why isn't the post fetched when I run the query with week 1?

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/tIzywRY4

I MariaDB 10.4.22

Comment: `But the date 2024-01-02 is in week 1` why do you think so? [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) says `If a date falls in the last week of the previous year, MySQL returns 0 if you do not use 2, 3, 6, or 7 as the optional mode argument`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/week/), by default the `week` function starts week numbers at 0.

The date `2024-01-02` is in the first week of the year, so the function will return `0` as the week number for that date.

You can vary that by setting the `mode` argument of the function. I will reproduce from the documentation the table of values you can use for this option and what they represent:

| Mode | 1st day of week | Range | Week 1 is the 1st week with |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sunday | 0-53 | a Sunday in this year |
| 1 | Monday | 0-53 | more than 3 days this year |
| 2 | Sunday | 1-53 | a Sunday in this year |
| 3 | Monday | 1-53 | more than 3 days this year |
| 4 | Sunday | 0-53 | more than 3 days this year |
| 5 | Monday | 0-53 | a Monday in this year |
| 6 | Sunday | 1-53 | more than 3 days this year |
| 7 | Monday | 1-53 | a Monday in this year |

Therefore, to get the result you're expecting you could use mode 3, for example

```
SELECT 
  amount,
  date_format(p_date, '%u') as week, 
  date_format(p_date, '%Y') as year
FROM 
  test
WHERE 
  week(p_date, 3) = 1
  AND year(p_date) = 2024
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/5KZmU18G

Comment: The mode argument was new to me. Thanks!